# May you live until one hundred and twenty

Tags: commentaries, language, gematria-numerology

The phrase: May you live until one hundred and twenty (עד מאה ועשרים) is a famous one derived from different verses of the Tenach.

But I would like to know if there is any deeper (gematrial) meaning in the words ‘one hundred and twenty’? Do the numbers 100 and 20 or 120, or the words ‘hundred’ and ‘twenty’, or ‘hundred and twenty’, have specific meanings in Jewish thought?